# Batch compress pdf files and maintain folder structures

Tags: windows, batch, pdf, compression, adobe-acrobat

I'm looking for a way to batch compress PDFs but also keep the folder structures. Currently, we're using Acrobat, but it doesn't keep the folder structure when outputting. Is there a way to configure this option in Acrobat or another program?

I know there are command-line tools like ImageMagick but I'd prefer an option that wouldn't be overwhelming for normal users.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [4dots Free PDF Compress](https://www.4dots-software.com/free-pdf-compress/)

You can select and batch compress whole folders and their subfolders with PDF documents.